# What is a better way to solve this exercise in more Immutable way?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability, tail-recursion, immutable-collections

I am trying to solve a problem on HackerRank. I am trying to solve this problem in more functional way (using immutability). I have attempted a solution but I am not fully confident about it.

Here’s a link to the problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

My mutable solution goes like this:

```
/**
  * Mutable solution
  * MSet => mutable set is used
  * val pairs => it is delclared var and getting reassigned
  */

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set => MSet}

def sockMerchant2(n: Int, ar: Array[Int]): Int = {
  val sockInventory : MSet[Int] = MSet.empty[Int]
  var pairs = 0
  ar.foreach { elem =>
    if(sockInventory.contains(elem)) {
      pairs = pairs + 1
      sockInventory -= elem
    } else sockInventory += elem
  }
  pairs
}

sockMerchant(5, Array(1,2,1,2,4,2,2))
```

Immutable version of the same solution:

```
/**
  * Solution with tail recursion.
  * Immutable Set is used. No variable is getting reassigned
  * How it is getting handled internally ?
  * In each iteration new states are assigned to same variables.
  * @param n
  * @param ar
  * @return
  */

import scala.annotation.tailrec
def sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: Array[Int]): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(arr: Array[Int], counter: Int, sockInventory: Set[Int]): Int ={
    if(arr.isEmpty) counter
    else if(sockInventory.contains(arr.head))
      loop(arr.tail, counter +1, sockInventory-arr.head)
    else loop(arr.tail, counter, sockInventory + arr.head)
  }
  loop(ar, 0, Set.empty)
}

sockMerchant(5, Array(1,2,1,2,4,2,2))
```

What is ideal way to solve this problem, considering functional programming principles?

Comment: `ar.groupBy(identity).map(_._2.length/2).sum`

Comment: @jwvh Thank you for the solution. It is passing all test cases. I am assuming "Identity" refers to keys of Map generated. Here the data type of array element is Int, so the domain for keys would be Int. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: That is correct. `identity` means "group your elements by their values". In other words, if `a == b` then they will be grouped together.  The Array#groupBy type signature is `groupBy[K](f: (T) => K): Map[K,Array[T]]`. Since `ar` is `Array[Int]` then the `groupBy(identity)` returns `Map[Int, Array[Int]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First possibility is to use pattern matching:

```
  def sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: Array[Int]): Int = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(list: List[Int], counter: Int, sockInventory: Set[Int]): Int =
    list match {
      case Nil =>
        counter
      case x::xs if sockInventory.contains(x) =>
        loop(xs, counter +1, sockInventory-x)
      case x::xs =>
        loop(xs, counter, sockInventory + x)
    }
    loop(ar.toList, 0, Set.empty)
  }
```

If you change the `Array` to a `List` you get a good readable solution.

An even *more functional* solution would be to use `folding`:

```
  def sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: Array[Int]): Int = {
    ar.foldLeft((0, Set.empty[Int])){case ((counter, sockInventory), x: Int) =>
      if (sockInventory.contains(x))
        (counter +1, sockInventory-x)
        else
        (counter, sockInventory + x)
    }._1
  }
```

This is a bit harder to read/ understand - so when I started I preferred the version with `recursion`.

And as *jwvh* shows in its comment - if you cannot do it in one line with **Scala** - you may miss something;).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Both solutions are working and passing all the test cases.